# Slow down audio speed

Tags: java, audio

So in the program below, it speeds up an audio file and makes it sound as if the person has a "helium voice". This was done by changing the index value, and when you increase it, the file gets higher pitch and faster. I was wondering if there was a way to do the opposite and make the audio play slower and have a deeper voice.

```
public void helium(String sourceFile, String targetFile)
{
    Sound sourceObj = new Sound(sourceFile);                               
    Sound target = new Sound(targetFile);   
    int sampleValue = 0;                                              
    int targetIndex = 0;                                                

    for(int index = 0; index < sourceObj.getLength(); index+=2)
    {
        sampleValue = sourceObj.getSampleValueAt(index);                    
        target.setSampleValueAt(targetIndex,sampleValue);                   
        targetIndex++;                                                      
    }
    target.play();  

}
```

Comment: Use negative values?

Comment: if you put negative values for the index, it will just cause an error

Comment: What if you increment by 1 and use `index / 2`?

Comment: I just tried that, but it just makes the audio sound normal and only plays half of the audio.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reducing the size of the sample by half, double the size of the sample, and use each value twice. I'm sure there are more advanced approaches but this will make the wave form progress twice as slowly resulting in a lower-pitched sound.

I have to make some assumptions because you are using some non-standard Sound API that I'm not familiar with. To ensure that your sound is not too long for your target sample, I'm now limiting the index in the source to half the maximum size of your target sample (`index < target.getLength()/2`)

```
int sampleValue = 0;                                              
int targetIndex = 0;                                                

for(int index = 0; index < target.getLength()/2; index++)
{
    sampleValue = sourceObj.getSampleValueAt(index);                    
    target.setSampleValueAt(targetIndex, sampleValue);
    target.setSampleValueAt(targetIndex + 1, sampleValue);                   
    targetIndex += 2;                                                      
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to Java, but when I changed the code to what you wrote, it created an error saying "That index 443904, does not exist. The last valid index is 443903". I'm sorry, but I don't really know what that means if you could maybe change the code or interpret that for me.

Comment: @DannyM Updated the answer. See "To ensure that your sound is not too long for your target sample, I'm now limiting the index in the source to half the maximum size of your target sample (`index < target.getLength()/2`)"

Comment: thanks that did the trick. If you don't mind me asking, do you know why that error I said above was happening. (sorry i'm very new to programming)

Comment: It looks like your target `Sound` sample is created based on the length of a file on disk, and you cannot extend the length of the sample simply by setting a sample value at a higher index.  You may want to create your target Sound in a different way: `Sound target = new Sound(sourceObject.getLength() * 2);`  and then you loop can go up to `index < target.getLength()`, based on this Javadoc (but I can't verify as I don't have your library) http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~cs41/Classes/2007%2001%20Spring/CS%201315/jes/Sources/javadoc/SimpleSound.html#getNumSamples()

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be to double up every sample.

A less naive approach would be to split the difference between samples (linear interpolation).

The correct approach is to insert a zero in between each sample and then apply a low-pass filter that rejects any signals above half the sample rate. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling